# Twitter API returns 'Invalid or expired token.'

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth-2.0

I have a simple application that doesn't use very many packages. So I thought this would be the perfect opportunity to try out Deno, the one package I do require that isn't a third-party module is the Twitter API. No problem I thought since I don't need many of the functions it includes. I might as well write it myself!

So I wrote a function for generating an Bearer token using this [doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/token) from the Twitter docs:

```
function getOAuthBearer(consumer_key, consumer_secret) {
    const basic = Buffer.from(`${consumer_key}:${consumer_secret}`).toString('base64')
    const options = {
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${basic}`,
            'Content-Type': `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`
        },
        body: querystring.stringify({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        })
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) reject(error);
            else resolve(JSON.parse(body).access_token);
        });  
    });
}
```

Which works! I got my bearer token, so I wrote a function to fetch some `user_timeline` information from a request example from this [doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-2-0/application-only)

```
function getUserTimeline(bearer_token) {
    const options = {
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com//1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=100&screen_name=twitterapi',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Buffer.from(bearer_token).toString('base64'),
        }
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) reject(error);
            else resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        });  
    });
}
```

Which returns this:

> { errors: [ { code: 89, message: 'Invalid or expired token.' } ] }

Which is weird but I thought I could just invalidate the bearer and request a new one for which I wrote this function:

```
function invalideOAuthBearer(consumer_key, consumer_secret, bearer_token) {
    const basic = Buffer.from(`${consumer_key}:${consumer_secret}`).toString('base64');
    const options = {
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/invalidate_token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${basic}`,
            'Content-Type': `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`
        },
        body: querystring.stringify({
            'access_token': bearer_token
        })
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) reject(error);
            else resolve(JSON.parse(body));
        });  
    });
}
```

But this returns:

> { errors: [ { code: 348, message: 'Client application is not permitted to to invalidate this token.' } ] }

So now I'm somewhat stuck, I tried regenerating my credentials and that doesn't do much. I searched online but could only find old post of people saying it's a bug/infrastructure issue but since there are so many applications using the Twitter API this seems unlikely to me, and of course, there are people just recommending using a package like [twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter), which I would but like I said the Deno platform doesn't have any packages like this :(

Comment: I think your [this discussion](https://twittercommunity.com/t/oauth2-invalidate-token-not-working-with-sorry-that-page-does-not-exist-code-34-error/120646/6) is somehow related to your problem.

Comment: Hmm, yes it seems that way. I'll make a post there since the threat has died

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bearer token shouldn't be base64 encoded. Try this:

```
const options = {
        url: 'https://api.twitter.com//1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=100&screen_name=twitterapi',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer_token}`,
        }
    }
```